# Radiometric calibration of Sentinel-2 products

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, reflectance

How can I calibrate `Sentinel-2` products, to extract the `reflectance`?

I've downloaded few `Sentinel-2` products from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/s2/#/home, and opened them with `SNAP` but its radiometric calibration is dedicated only to `SAR` products.

On `ENVI`, the `Radiometric calibration` tool is seemingly only capable of extracting the `radiance`. What is the difference between the `radiance` and the `reflectance`? Is the estimation of the `radiance` counted as a radiometric calibration of a product?

Comment: Not entirely familiar with the sensor, other than an msi bird similar to landsat. If that's the case, its odd that it would load by default in radiance. Youre just doing classifications? Should plot you spectra in reflectance, and should be able to use that tool to do so. What is the textual result/error ? Algorithms ( regarding atmospheric correction, etc)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sentinel-2 Level 1C data are expressed in reflectance with a scaling factor, not in radiance.
You have to divide by 10000 to get the reflectance. In the preliminary products shown this autumn, you had to divide by 1000.

The scaling factor is given in the xml file at the root of the product directory.

```
<QUANTIFICATION_VALUE unit="none">10000</QUANTIFICATION_VALUE>
```

There is no offset and the no_data value is 0.

Comment: Can you tell me how the TOA reflectance is defined? I can't find the definition in any official document.

Comment: rho=(pi.L)/(Es cos theta_s) where L is TOA radiance, rho is TOA reflectance, Es is the sun irradiance, theta_s is the sun zenith angle, and pi.. is pi.

Comment: The sun irradiance Es must account for the Earth Sun distance variations

Comment: @O.Hagolle Is there a scaling factor for images from june 2016? I am unable to find this quantification value in the xml file and was hence wondering.

Comment: I am not aware of that. There are several xml files in a product, are you using the product xml or the granule xml ? It is in the product xml, with a name like that : S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20160727T183119_R008_V20160727T104250_20160727T104250.xml: