# Discrepancies in remotely sensed indices using Sentinel 2 Level 1C imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, vegetation-index, peru

I am hoping to derive a variety of vegetation indices for grasslands in Peru using Sentinel 2 data for one cloud free image in June 2016. But most of my indices are not in the range of the index. For example,

```
CRI 1- theoretical range is 0-15, range determined is -0.012 to 0.010
EVI- theoretical range is -1 to 1, range determined is -10755 to 10515
EVI 2- theoretical range is -1 to 1, range determined is -0.84 to 2.016
SAVI- theoretical range is -1 to 1, range determined is -1.31 to 1.31
MSAVI- theoretical range is -1 to 1, range determined is -5.506 to 1.43
```

Using raster calculator in ArcMap, I have appropriately used Float() and also multiplied all variables to 1.0 to overcome the data type problems. Also, I have checked to see if extreme index values pixels are clouds, or edges etc, but they happen to be within the image itself i.e for example EVI 2 values >1.0 are green vegetation pixels itself.

How do I determine is the indices I have calculated are correct? If not correct, what is the right to calculate each.

Comment: Did you use the DN or convert to reflectance?

Comment: @HDunn- Sentinel 2 Level 1 C data which is what I have used is TOA Reflectance 

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types

So I directly calculated the indices on the image itself.  I have read in some other posts about a scaling factor- http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173145/radiometric-calibration-of-sentinel-2-products 
but couldn't find the Quantification Value in the xml file of my image, so did not use any scaling factor either.

Answer (score 1):

@HDunn is right, 
you have to convert to reflectance using the quantification value (10000) which is in the product metadata (not the granule metadata).

For instance, EVI = G.(Nir-Red)/(Nir+C1.Red-C2.Blue+L)

If all the reflectances are multiplied by 10000, adding L=1 does not have much effect.

Comment: @O.Hagolle- you mean divide each band by 10000, not multiply.

Comment: To convert to reflectance, you need to divide by 10000. But if you don't convert, then your reflectances are multipled by 10000.